# How can I execute animations for multiple SKSprintNodes consecutively?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I already know how to run multiple animations on the same SKSpriteNode at once:

```
createPaths()
let myIcon1 = MyIcon(wIcon: "screen", iSize: iSize)
let move    = SKAction.follow(iconPath[0], asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 1)
let shrink  = SKAction.resize(byWidth: -iSize.width/2, height: -iSize.width/2, duration: 1)
let blur    = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.6, duration: 1)
let group   = SKAction.group([shrink, move, blur])
myIcon1.run(group)
```

But I have two more icons I would like to animate at the same time.

Granted, with just 3 icons total I din't see any lag if I do something like this:

```
myIcon1.run(group1)
myIcon2.run(group2)
myIcon3.run(group3)
```

But surely there is a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to do exactly as you did.

From the phrasing of the question, it sounds like maybe you were expecting `myIcon1.run(group1)` to finish before `myIcon2.run(group2)`.  If so, that's not the way that running actions works.  The `run` is just telling the sprite what to be doing, not actually doing it immediately.

By analogy, think of yourself as a film director.  You tell your actors (the sprites) what to do before the scene starts.  When you say "Action!" (i.e., the [update loop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/responding_to_frame-cycle_events) starts running) all the sprites start doing whatever you told them, but they're doing it independently.  Most of SpriteKit programming is structuring your app as reactions to things that happen as the scene plays out.  You can tell sprites to do something new whenever they finish their previous tasks (by having a completion block argument to `run`), tell them to stop whatever they're doing and do something else (cancel actions, add new ones), or have them react when external events happen (e.g., you get collision notifications from the physics engine or the user touches the screen).

Comment: No, I knew that those commands would run on their own. But what if I had 20 SKSpriteNodes who's animation I wanted to run at once? At some point I figured I'd reach a time lag if I had to tell "each one" Action.

Comment: At some point things will run out of steam, but it's impossible to say anything in general.  It depends on the device, the size of your textures, any effects being applied, physics and types of physics bodies being used, etc.